# How to take values from the dropdown in Dash?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I have to take the value from the dropdown menu into account. How do I do it?

```
   dcc.Dropdown(
    id = drop,
    options=[
        {'label': 'Earth', 'value': Earth},
        {'label': 'Mars', 'value': Mars},
        {'label': 'Jupiter', 'value': Jupiter}
    ],
    value='NAN'
),
dcc.Graph(
    id='Example Plot',
    figure= plot_object(value)
)
```

Comment: What do you mean taken into account? What do you want to accomplish?